# Materialize CSS checkbox is not aligned properly

Tags: html, css, materialize

*Noticed this issue in my own web development*.

With my markup (including Materialize):

```html
<label>
   <input style="padding-top: 5px;" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" />
   <span>Hyper (+$5)</span>
</label>
```

When I check the result of this, I get a checkbox that looks like:

[image: image of Hyper-labelled checkbox, with a mis-aligned checkbox]

How can I fix this so it's properly aligned with my text?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS style:

```css
[type="checkbox"] .filled-in :not(:checked) + span:not(.lever):after {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

[type="checkbox"] .filled-in:checked + span:not(.lever):after {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Which will cause your alignment to be fixed. You can also change your SCSS to-compile sheet in `forms/_checkboxes.scss` at two locations.

As-of today (September 2020), add under 134 and 158:

```
margin-top: 3px;
```